# what happens when 2 different functions calls the same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I was experimenting with Asyncio in python, and thought what will happen if call 2 different Asyncio functions running concurrently to  non-async fuction. 
so did like this `

```
def calc(number):
    while True:
        return(number * number)

async def one():
    while True:
        a = calc(5)
        print(a)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def two():
    while True:
        a = calc(2)
        print(a)
        await asyncio.sleep(0) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    import os
    import uvloop
    import asyncio
    loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.create_task(one()) 
    loop.create_task(two())
    loop.run_forever()
```

I thought program will freeze in cal function (while loop), but the program is printing results concurrently.Could any one explain me why this is not getting stuck in the while loop, Thanks.

`

Comment: functions called from within the async functions will be async to the main context even if the functions are synchronous in the async context

Comment: You have a return in `calc`. The function exits during the first iteration of the while loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/978961/dirn you mean return statements can breaks  any loop?

Comment: The return statement exits the function and returns control to its caller 100% of the time. You could retaliate `calc` as `def calc(number): return number + number` and it would behave identically to what you have now.